# MySQL unique key/constraint for pair of values regardless of which column they're in

Tags: mysql, unique-key

How do I apply a unique key to the following table and requirements?

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `item_id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
);
```

Here, `item_id` and `friend_id` both relate to same parent field (Foreign Key). It would not matter if `friend_id`, `item_id` appear in order, because it also means the same.

For example, if values (5, 7) appear in the row, it should not accept (7, 5) as a new row - because it is logically a duplicate record.

Now, how do I add a unique key or some constraints to this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baring a more palatable solution, you can always simulate a constraint by using a trigger.

```
create trigger chk_friends_unique before update on friends
  for each row 
   begin  
    if (exists(
      SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE 
        (friend_id = new.item_id AND item_id = new.friend_id)
        OR (item_id = new.item_id AND friend_id = new.friend_id)
    )) then
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unique constrain violated';
    end if; 
   end;
```

Honestly though if you can handle the ordering restriction, then @Joop Eggen's answer a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `item_id < friend_id` which can be done with a CHECK constraint.
This removes the redundance (7, 5) from (5, 7).

```
CHECK (item_id < friend_id)
CONSTRAINT UC_item_friend UNIQUE (item_id, friend_id)
```

Correspondingly the code must be careful to keep this order.

Purists might argue against this technique that a subrelation of friend_ids and item_ids should be made.

Comment: This is a creative and smart answer if you can deal with the order limitation.